# SBSMonitoring.mdf reached limit

Tags: monitoring, database, windows-sbs-2008

I have SBS 08 Standart.
I have some Error in my Event Viewer with MSSQL$SBSMONITORING Event id 1105, 1827:

> Could not allocate space for object
>   'dbo.EventLog'.'PK_EventLog' in
>   database 'SBSMonitoring' because the
>   'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create
>   disk space by deleting unneeded files,
>   dropping objects in the filegroup,
>   adding additional files to the
>   filegroup, or setting autogrowth on
>   for existing files in the filegroup.
>
> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE
>   failed because the resulting
>   cumulative database size would exceed
>   your licensed limit of 4096 MB per
>   database.

I tried to schrink the database, worked for SBSMonitoring_log.LDF but nothing for the SBSMonitoring.mdf, still 4096MB.

I don't know how to reinstall the monitoring.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you upgrade the SQL Server to 2012 Express? The limit was raised to 10gb there.

THen check your data pruning. You can not shrinkgthe file because there is so much data. There must be a way to have SBS drop old data. Maybe you just forgot to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot shrink the database as it is is totally full, shrinking can only work if there is free space in the files for the database.

One workaround can be found [here](http://blog.korteksolutions.com/the-sbsmonitoring-database-is-nearing-maximum-size-on-sbs-2008/) that will sort out the problem for you by reducing the size of the database. There is also a link to create a new totally blank database that might be of more use to you.

The script mentioned in the link above can also be found at microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;981939).